# How can I send an email (containing spaces) through a button on Google Sites?

Tags: javascript, html, css, email, google-sites

I need to write a button that opens an email on the users computer when clicked. Sounds simple but I am having far to much trouble with it, I am using Google Sites and I have my code inside a HTML box to allow the use of CSS. I currently have some buttons that open an email but I can't get the spaces in the email to work as normal spaces.

I initially tried making a form button to submit to a webpage, the form cutoff everything after the initial '?' in the URL. Made sense when I realised what I was asking of it. I added extra hidden form elements with the content of the title and body that I want in the email. By using this method I can't see a way of allowing spaces to be put into the URL without them being converted to something else.

The code below is the current HTML I have, it produces emails with '+' instead of ' ' and '%2520' instead of ' '.

```
<style>
    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1000px;
    }
    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    input {  
        width: 100%;
    }
    .hidden {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Heading 1</th>
                <th>Heading 2</th>
                <th>Heading 3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <td>Example Text<td>
                <td>Example Text<td>
                <td><form action="mailto:example@email.com?"><input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="Title with lots of spaces"/><input type="hidden" name="body" value="Body with lots of spaces"/><input type="submit" value="Email" /></form></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Example Text<td>
                <td>Example Text<td>
                <td><form action="mailto:example@email.com?"><input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="Title%20with%20lots%20of%20spaces"/><input type="hidden" name="body" value="Body%20with%20lots%20of%20spaces"/><input type="submit" value="Email" /></form></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

The two buttons I have in that example should produce the following URLs respectively.

> mailto:example@email.com?Subject=Title+with+lots+of+spaces&Body+with+lots+of+spaces
>
> mailto:example@email.com?Subject=Title%2520with%2520lots%2520of%2520spaces&Body%2520with%2520lots%2520of%2520spaces

I realise that JavaScript might solve this issue but Google Sites puts the contents of HTML Boxes in shells similar to iframes. This stops new tabs being opened from inside the shell and therefore stops email popups.

Is there a way to use my workaround form submission with spaces or is there a simple way of opening emails with JavaScript on a Google Site?

Any help would be appreciated, I hope that what I am trying to do is achievable on the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working...

### A Solution

I tried using JavaScript but that wouldn't allow me to open new tabs due to the protection on Google Sites. I found an article that most people might find useful: http://blog.ncce.org/2013/12/10/put-javascript-into-google-sites/
By using this solution you should be able to use JavaScript to navigate to different webpages, use alerts etc.

I couldn't use this method. I am doing this for work and my organisation currently has a contract with Google that restricts all access to the Google Sites/Google Drive to only those within the organisation. Because of this, the site couldn't access any of the files I uploaded and produced an error.

### My Solution

The solution I came up with somehow bypasses the issue I had with the other solution and allows me to use JavaScript to encode the spaces as %20 (also allows me to close the extra tab after it loads).

I used Google App Script to display a HTML element which contains a button that uses JavaScript to open the email URL.
You can add a Google App Script to your site using the guidance here:
https://support.google.com/sites/answer/1224162?hl=en

Google Apps Script is new to me so a couple of notes:

1. It took me ages to even find the thing... Cog -> Manage Site -> App Scripts
2. To run the script save your files, save as new version (File -> Manage Versions -> New Version) and then publish those changes (Publish -> Deploy as Web App)

**My Code**

Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
    .evaluate();
}
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1000px;
    }

    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    tr.even {
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }

    button {  
        width: 100%;
    }
</style> 
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Descrition</th>
                    <th>Submit</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="even">
                    <td>Example Text</td>
                    <td>Example Text</td>
                    <td><button onclick="var x = window.open('mailto:example@email.com?Subject=Title%20with%20lots%20of%20spaces&Body=Body%20with%20lots%20of%20spaces'); setTimeout(function () { x.close();}, 500);">Email</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps people.